# Launch External Jar through Java Application

Tags: java

Currently, I have an Java Standalone Swing Application.

Now, when user clicks on the button in the Swing Application, I would like to launch another Java Application (Say : calculator.jar)

May I know what is the portable way to do so? So that it will work in multiple OS?

Comment: Please clarify: is that "other jar" in the classpath, do you want to launch it in the same VM or in the separate?

Comment: how do you launch it in separate VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use [`Desktop#open()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) or just put it in classpath and invoke its `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use java to run the jar.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar calc.jar");
```

Comment: what happens if the java path is not set?