# Open java application from another

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, call

I need your help. I have 2 applications in Java. I have one of them to invoke from the other. ie the application "A" press a button that opens my application "B"
someone has an idea of ​​how you can get to do this?

PS: both applications were developed in Java swing with netbeans.

Comment: Do you want them executed within the context of the JVM or should application "B" be started within it's own JVM

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5696386/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one contain another and have the one being contained set to false, visibilty, then change the visibility. Something like this

```
public class AFrame extends JFrame {
     private JButton jbt = new JButton("Open Window");
     private BFrame jfrm = new BFrame();

    public class AFrame(){
        add(jbt);
        jfrm.setVisibile(false);
        add(jfrm);

        jbt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                jfrm.setVisibile(true);
            }
        });
    }
}


public class BFrame extends JFrame {

    public BFrame(){

   }

}
```

When "Open Window" button is pressed, the `BFrame` is set to visible, then appears. The `AFrame` is the starting program, which contains a `BFrame`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Desktop.getDesktop().open()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) function

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("PATH-TO-YOUR-APPLICATION-JAR\\yourapplication.jar"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Or put the jar file in the class path and invokes its main() method.

**Ref:**

1. [Launch External Jar through Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821624/2628911)
2. [Running an external jar file by pressing a JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988840/2628911)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do by using *dispose()* method with frame object of *program A* to close the program A and *setDefaultCloseOperation* to HIDE_ON_CLOSE because if you set it to exit_on_close it will terminate and also you need to call the constructor or method of program B before dispose() to start the B program

```
//in the method were you want to stop the first program and start second program
AFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(AFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
new ProgramB(); //calling constructor of class B
AFrame.dispose();
```